# Making two jquery scripts work together

Tags: jquery

I'm a jquery newby and was wondering how I could get these two scripts to "talk" to each other:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
<div id="selextender"></div>
<p><a href="#" id="seladd">Add</a></p>
</fieldset>
</form>    

$(function () {
     $('a#seladd').click(function () {
         $('<p><select name="items[]"><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option></select><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></p>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#selextender');
         return false;
     });
     $('.remove').live('click', function () {
         $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {
             $(this).empty();
             return false;
         });
     });
 });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UV6Tw/

The above duplicates my select boxes - how do I incorporate the following to dynamically add the select box options and still duplicate the select boxes?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('select[name="products"]').focus(function () {
         if ($('option', this).length < 2) {
             $.getJSON('products.php?product=' + $(this).attr('value'), outputProducts);
         }
     })
 });

 function outputProducts(response) {
     $('select[name="products"]').html(response.html).attr('selectedIndex', response.index);
     return true;
 }

<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="products">
<option selected="selected">Please select</option>
</select>   
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: I'd suggest rewording your post a little. Posting some HTML would also be handy for us to look at. For example, are you just wanting the second script to run as the first script is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given some html that looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<div id="selextender"></div>
<p><a href="#" id="seladd">Add</a></p>
</form>
```

You can add a new select, and when it is focused load your data using ajax:

```
//set a counter
var i = $('input').size() + 1;   

//add select
$('a#seladd').click(function() {
    $('<p><select name="product"><option value="0">Please select</option></select><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></p>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#selextender');         
    return false;
});

//fadeout selected item and remove
$('.remove').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).empty();
        return false;
    });
});

// dynamically load options when focused.
$('select[name="product"]').live('focus',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children(':first').text('please wait.... loading.');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'products.php?product=' + $this.attr('value'),
        success: function(data){
           $this.html(data);
        }                
    });
});
```

I have mocked up a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SJP8h/ (however, note this uses jsfiddle's mocked ajax calls)